# Windows C++ Integer Array Heap Corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, int

I have been working on sorting algorithms for school and have come across a strange issue. When ever I create an integer array bigger than six elements large I get breaks in "free.c" and heap corruption errors.

The code I have narrowed it down to is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int * pie = new int(7);
    pie[6] = 1;

    cout << pie[6];

    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes you need to assign more than just the last value, however I can get this error on Visual Studio 2012 and 2010 on multiple computers, in Linux this code works perfectly fine however.

Is this an issue with Windows, have I been doing dynamic int arrays wrong forever or what?

Note:After running this several times, sometimes the output in VS will say something about adding a heap protection shunt which seems to resolve the test throwing the exception but still doesn't solve the issue in larger applications (and I would feel bad having to need such protection applied to my code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new int(7)` allocates a single `int`, value 7. It doesn't allocate space for 7 `int` values.

Comment: Woah! I can't believe I was doing that >.< Thanks for your super fast reply! It might need to be in a new question but why was I aloud to go to that point without any issues/Linux compilers not yelling at me? Was I just eating up memory that I didn't own?

Comment: Because C++ never gives you that protection (it sacrifices it for speed). You just going to have to learn to program carefully, and follow best practices. This is very very important. One of the most important best practices is to not use pointers unless you need them. In your case you should have a vector instead of trying to allocate your own memory.

Answer (score 7):

In this case you are allocating a single integer which has the value `7` but treating it like an array of `7` elements.  You need to do an actual array allocation

```
int* pie = new int[7];
```

Also wouldn't hurt to free the memory at the end of `main` :)

```
delete[] pie;
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you need to use:

```
int* pie = new int[7];
```

Otherwise, you only allocate **one int**.

Executing the code below, will overwrite whatever is beyond the array boundaries.

```
int * pie = new int(7);
pie[6] = 1;
```

This can lead to hard-to-track random bugs. For instance if it overwrites a pointer…

**More informations in: [C++ Dynamic Memory allocations](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)**

> **Operators new and new[]**
>
> In order to request dynamic memory we use the operator new. new is followed by a data type specifier and -if a
>   sequence of more than one element is required- the number of these
>   within brackets []. It returns a pointer to the beginning of the new
>   block of memory allocated. Its form is: 
>          pointer = new type pointer = new type [number_of_elements]
>          The first expression is used to allocate memory to contain one single    element of type type. The second one is used to assign a
>   block (an    array) of elements of type type, where number_of_elements
>   is an    integer value representing the amount of these. For example:

```
int * bobby; 
bobby = new int [5];
```

> In this case, the system dynamically assigns space for five elements
>   of type int and returns a pointer to the first element of the
>   sequence, which is assigned to bobby. Therefore, now, bobby points to
>   a valid block of memory with space for five elements of type int.

> **Operators delete and delete[]**
>
> Since the necessity of dynamic memory is usually limited to specific
>   moments within a program, once it is no longer needed it should be
>   freed so that the memory becomes available again for other requests of
>   dynamic memory. This is the purpose of the operator delete, whose
>   format is:

```
delete pointer;
delete [] pointer;
```

> The first expression should be used to delete memory allocated for a
>   single element, and the second one for memory allocated for arrays of
>   elements.
>
> The value passed as argument to delete must be either a pointer to a
>   memory block previously allocated with new, or a null pointer (in the
>   case of a null pointer, delete produces no effect).